# Add Smart Lock screen security options to Amazon Fire HD 8?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, tablet, smart-lock

[Smart Lock](https://get.google.com/smartlock/) is present in vanilla Lollipop 5.* but isn't included in Amazon Fire HD 8, which is based on Lollipop.

Can Smart Lock be added/enabled on Amazon Fire HD 8 tablet devices?

Comment: If app-based solutions are acceptable, there are some "smart unlocker apps" available, see e.g. my related app listing [Unlock with WiFi](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation#group_435) (also includes apps additionally supporting Bluetooth).

Answer (score 0):

Only a few devices support Smart Lock(mainly Motorola and Samsung)

If you are having trouble finding Smart Lock, try

- Go to Settings > Security > Screen lock > Set the Pin Lock
- After setting the Pin Lock go back to the Security Menu, at the Bottom of 
  security menu you will find Trust Agent
- Go to Settings > Security > Trust Agent
- Enable Smart lock ( Google )
- Select Smart Lock